# Comparing string to integer in C structure

Tags: c

Trying to make a program to define the structure for vehicle data: manufacturer (string), model (string), power in kWh (int) and price (float),program initializes data for 10 vehicles, asks the user for data on the minimum power and maximum price of vehicles requested by the user and prints data on all vehicles that meet the entered data, thanks in advance for any help

```
struct cars {
    char manufacturer[30];
    char model[30];
    int power;
    float price;
};

int main() {
    struct cars S1[100], S2[10] = {{ "Bmw", "x3", 125, 9800 },
                                   { "Audi", "a3", 84, 12000 },
                                   { "Golf", "mk5", 40, 7000 },
                                   { "Citroen", "c4", 60, 10200 },
                                   { "Mercedes", "c220", 70,5000 },
                                   { "Mazda", "cx", 170, 25000 },
                                   { "Fiat", "punto", 35, 3200 },
                                   { "Skoda", "octavia", 72, 6500 },
                                   { "Maserati", "m5", 220, 29000 },
                                   { "Ferrari", "488p", 300, 100000 }};
   int minpow;
   float maxprice;
   int i, j;
   printf("Min power of the vehicle: %d\n", minpow);
   printf("Max price of the vehicle: %f", maxprice);
   for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
       if (strcmp(S2[i].power > minpow) && (strcmp(S2[i].price < maxprice) > 0) {
         printf("your vehicles:%s %s", S2[i].manufacturer, S2.model);
       }
   }
```

Comment: I believe you can parse command line input as int and float. And then just do a normal comparison. `scanf("%d", &minpow);`

Comment: This syntax is very wrong: `strcmp(S2[i].price<maxprice)`. Some textbook study is needed, perhaps. The whole expression has imbalanced parentheses too. Also `for(i=0;i<9;i++)` should be `<10`

Comment: Also printing `minpow` and `maxprice` from uninitialised variables and with no data input. The code seems to be 'broad guesswork' and the question needs more focus.

Comment: As an aside, avoid storing money in floats, because you will get rounding errors. Use for example integer with cents (or equivalent) amount.

Comment: bole, Why does code print `maxprice` rather than try to read it?

Answer (score 1):

There are some things in your code that don't seem right.

1. To get data from the user, you should use `scanf` function instead of `printf` like this:

```
printf("Min power of the vehicle: ");
scanf("%d",&minpow);
printf("\nMax price of the vehicle: ");
scanf("%f",&maxprice);
printf("\n");
```

Note the `&` before the variables like in `&minpow` to pass the variable's address to `scanf` function. This way, your program will be saving the data in the correct format (`int` and `float`)

2.Then, in the for loop, you don't need to use `strcmp` since you are not longer comparing strings. Your loop code should look something like this:

```
 for(i=0;i<9;i++)
 {
     if(S2[i].power>minpow && S2[i].price<maxprice)
     {
         printf("your vehicles:%s %s\n",S2[i].manufacturer,S2.model);
     }
 }
```

Iago.

Comment: Minor: `.price` does not need to be less than `maxprice`, just less than or equal.  Similar concern for `..power`.  But as you say "look _something_ like this".

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the `atoi` function. It is generally not useful when trying to parse errors because when it fails it returns 0 or -1 (which could very well be the value contained in the string), but in your case none of these outputs count as valid values for `minpow` or `maxprice`.
My suggestion would be:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // atoi
#include <stdio.h> // scanf, printf

int main() {
   char minpow_str[10];
   char maxprice_str[10];

   int minpow = 0;
   int maxprice = 0;

   for(;;) {
     printf("minimum power desired : ");
     scanf("%9s", minpow_str);
     printf("max price desired: ");
     scanf("%9s", maxprice_str);

     minpow = atoi(minpow_str);
     maxprice = atoi(maxprice_str);
 
     if (minpow > 0 && maxprice > 0)
       break;

     printf("invalid input values\n");
   }
   // rest of your code
}
```

To make it clear, 10 is the length I chose but you can put any length you'd like the user's input to be. The arguments for the `scanf` function limit reading input to that length.
Edit: As comments mention, `%9s` makes it so scanf can null terminate the string read in case theres is 9 or more chars to be read.

Comment: `atoi` should be avoided since it invokes undefined behavior in case or errors. Use `strtol` instead.

Comment: `price` is a `float` anyway

Comment: @WeatherVane I guess I just answered the question being asked without looking deeply into the code :P (I honestly checked the struct and saw only integers). Still, mapping this solution to floats its a matter of changing `atoi` for `atof`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel sure, I'll edit the answer now.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel  now it should be fine.

Comment: @carce-bo: Yes, it looks good now. I have now deleted my outdated comments. I had already upvoted your question, so I unfortunately cannot upvote again.

Comment: Please stop advising people to use `atoi` on unsanitized user input, as explained [here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/465515/tribal-knowledge-atoi-is-evil) (as well as many other sources). Also, your input buffers are one byte short, making your program vulnerable to buffer overflow.

Comment: carce-bo, Given `char minpow_str[10]; ... scanf("%10s", minpow_str);` --> Off by 1.  The _width_ should be 1 less than size.  `"%10s"` --> `"%9s"`.  Consider `" %9[0-9]"` to avoid reading non-digits and UB from `atoi()`.  Also best to check return value from `scanf()`.